# How to have a main Image and then columns underneth bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive-design

I am working on a bootstrap site, and I want to model it off a certain design pattern. I really like the columns underneath a main banner or image style, but I don't know how I would design this. An example site would be the freashbooks.com home page. It has the blue banner and then the three columns underneath it.

Comment: You could check out the GetSkeleton framework instead of Bootstrap. It has a very easy to use grid system that accomplishes exactly what you're looking for. http://www.getskeleton.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you already viewed the Bootstrap examples section?
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples.html

The basic marketing site is a good jumping off point for what you want to accomplish. 
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html